# Kentico - New Tab on a Specific Page Type

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I would like to know if there is a way to create a new tab when editing pagetype information, for example they usually show Page, Design, Form, Properties and Security, I would like to add a custom one to display some information.

Any suggestion?
Attached an image with the part I am talking about in the CMS.
[PageType Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlyN3.png)

Answer (score 2):

There is a great example of this on [DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com) that will allow you to [add Google page speed insights](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/adding-a-google-pagespeed-utility-to-kentico) to the Pages application.  If you walk through that, it should give you everything you need to know.  You can then have something that looks like this:
[image: extra tab added to preview]

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by adding a new UI element to the **Modules -> Content -> User interface -> CMS/Administration/Content management/Pages/Edit** section.